# Why @input doesn't load the data in the variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am trying to pass info between components of the following way

**Parent view**

```
<div class="board">
    <app-ad [ad]="Title"></app-ad>
</div>
```

**Child component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ad',
  templateUrl: './ad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ad.component.less']
})
export class AdComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  ad: string;

  constructor() { console.log(this.ad) }//undefined

  ngOnInit() {console.log(this.ad) }//undefined

}
```

**Child view**

```
Title: {{ad}}
```

When I load the page, the variable isn't set.

Thanks

Comment: What are ou expecting to pass to AdComponent ? "title" as string or variable `title`?

Comment: How do you know it’s not set? How is title being set in the parent component?

Comment: Can you add parent component to you question ? It will be helpful !

Comment: You're not using this input variable anywhere so how have you confirmed that it's not being set?

Comment: I want pass the value to the another component, I know because I put log into constructor and into ngOnInit and only appear undefined

Comment: Something is wrong in your parent component title

Comment: if you just want to pass a string for testing, write it like this: `[ad]="'Title'"` in the parent component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your parent component, more specifically in a way how you pass the variable to `[ad]`. That would work fine if `Title` was an actual variable.

```
<app-ad [ad]="Title"></app-ad>
```

**Parent**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  Title = 'someTitle';
}
```

However if you want to pass the string value directly to template make sure to quote it

```
<div class="board">
    <app-ad [ad]="'Title'"></app-ad>
</div>
```